# Kotlin val assignment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Ran into this and wanted to do this with the least amount of repetitive code.  In Java I would do it this way (being an old Java programmer). For reference, `data` is a `Map<String, String>`.

```
Class action = SomeActivity.class;
if (data != null && data.get("abc") != null) {
    if (data.get("abc").contains("details")) {
        action = OtherActivity.class;
    } ... //may have more ifs for other contains()
}

Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, action);
```

I wanted to do the same in Kotlin but not repeat null conditions and use multiple assignment lines.  This is what I have so far.

```
val action = data["abc"]?.let {
    if (it.contains("details")) {
        OtherActivity::class.java
    } else {
        SomeActivity::class.java
    }
} ?: kotlin.run { SomeActivity::class.java }

val intent = Intent(this, action)
```

To me the Java looks more efficient than Kotlin here, with Kotlin I have two assignment lines repeated the `SomeActivity::class.java`, whereas in Java I can set the variable to one class and if and only if all the null and if condition checks out will it assign the new class.  So is there a way to do this in Kotlin without repeated assignment lines for `SomeActivity::class.java`?

Comment: The Kotlin code you posted is not equivalent to the Java code. For example where is the `if (data != null)` equivalent?

Comment: It isn't the same, as mTak mentioned. The missing `data != null` can be exlained by the map being a non-null type, but the main problem is that the Java code doesn't use a final variable. `val action` declares a final variable

Comment: You can also just use something similar to your java code and a `var action` if you like.

Comment: It's amazing 4 answers a bunch of comments and not one up vote for the question. SO should make a policy that if you take the time to answer a question it should be an automatic up-vote for the question.  If i take time to answer something I always up-vote the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the provided code, the following should work:

```
val intent = Intent(this, 
   data?.takeIf { it["abc"]?.contains("details") == true }
       ?.let { OtherActivity::class.java } 
       ?: SomeActivity::class.java
)
```

---

If you have additional branches, then of course you should use a `when` statement.

```
val abc = data?.get("abc")

val action = when {
    abc == null -> SomeActivity::class.java
    abc.contains("details") -> OtherActivity::class.java
    // other branches
    else -> SomeActivity::class.java
}
val intent = Intent(this, action)
```

Comment: Hmm. Someone's out for blood, downvoting everything that uses a `when` statement. Weird.

Comment: What is the benefit of using `takeIf` here?

Comment: You can combine `takeIf {}?.let {} ?:` for a single check re-assignment. It's shorter than having to extract an `if else` with null-checks inbetween. But the `when` statement is clearer, I admit.

Comment: I am not so sure if it's really shorter ;-) thanks for the clarification though

Comment: Not shorter I guess, but it does replace nesting with chaining - sometimes nicer, sometimes not :D

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the following will work for you:

```
val action = if (data?.get("abc")?.contains("details") == true) {
    OtherActivity::class.java
} else SomeActivity::class.java
val intent = Intent(this, action)
```

Note, you need the `== true` because the left part of the condition may still be `null` in which case the condition will result to: `null == true`, which then basically just returns the `SomeActivity::class.java`.

If you like ~one liners or `when`:

```
val intent = Intent(this, when {
  data?.get("abc")?.contains("details") == true -> OtherActivity::class.java
  /* Other conditions */ 
  else -> SomeActivity::class.java
})
```

Finally you could also just use the same construct as you had in Java by using `var` instead and specifying your general type, e.g.:

```
var action : Class<*> = SomeActivity::class.java
if (data?.get("abc")?.contains("details") == true) { 
  // Or add the conditions you actually had
  action = OtherActivity::class.java
}
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, action);
```

Comment: Seems to be controversial what I did.. :-)

Comment: In addition to a downvote a statement what's actually wrong would help everyone... I don't see anything wrong with it... It's probably just not as nice as it could be ;-)

Comment: If you try and use var action and then reassign the IDE complains at action = OtherActivity::class.java

Comment: Ah thanks... Finally a comment that helps... So setting the type then should help, e.g. something like `: Class<*>` or similar, right?

Comment: I think it should be `Class<out Activity>`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that makes definitely sense. The OP however also used `Class` so that is at least nearly equivalent ;-)

Comment: The third code snippet is more of what I was looking for but some of my team members don't like using var whenever they can they use val.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [when](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) block to do it neatly:

```
val abc = data["abc"]
val action = when {
    abc == null -> OtherActivity::class.java
    abc.contains("details") -> DetailsActivity::class.java
    abc.contains("somedata") -> SomeActivity::class.java
    abc.contains("otherdata") -> UnknownActivity::class.java
    else -> DefaultActivity::class.java
}
```

Or without repeating variable name:

```
val action = data["abc"].run {
    when {
        this == null -> OtherActivity::class.java
        contains("details") -> DetailsActivity::class.java
        contains("somedata") -> SomeActivity::class.java
        contains("otherdata") -> UnknownActivity::class.java
        else -> DefaultActivity::class.java
    } 
}
```

Or if you can afford to use equals instead of contains:

```
val action = when(abc) {
    null -> OtherActivity::class.java
    "details" -> DetailsActivity::class.java
    "somedata" -> SomeActivity::class.java
    "otherdata" -> UnknownActivity::class.java
    else -> DefaultActivity::class.java
}
```

Note that catching `null` as the first case lets other branches smart-cast to non-nullable type.

Comment: I wish I could use the when but the data coming in for abc key has unique number at the end each time so it will never be the same.  its actually page/details/{somenumber}, hence why I have to use contains.

Comment: data["abc"].run errors in the IDE about not enough info to infer R.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in this way

```
    val action = data["abc"]?.let {
        if (it.contains("details")) OtherActivity::class.java
            else SomeActivity::class.java
    }

    val intent = Intent(this,action)
```

if data["abc"] is null the let block is not called. so you can do this.

prevent null assignment (if deta["abc"

```
   val action= data["abc"]?.let {
        if (it.contains("details")) OtherActivity::class
            else SomeActivity::class
    } ?: DefaultActivity::class

    val intent = Intent(this,action.java)
```

Comment: What if data["abc"] is not there does action get assigned, no.

Comment: it will be null. if you need default action then you can set that. or you also check the action is null or not then crate intent

Answer (score -1):

You can use `when`, and an intermediate `null` to not repeat the `else` branch.

```
val action: KClass<out Activity> = data?.get("abc")?.let {
   when {
     it.contains("details") -> OtherActivity::class
     it.contains("bla")     -> BlaActivity::class
     else                   -> null
  }
} ?: SomeActivity::class

val intent = Intent(this, action.java)
```

Note that `data["abc"]` will **not** work if `data` can be null!